# Data structure - Big O of access and indexing. What do they really mean?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, time-complexity, big-o

I found two articles online:

[First](http://bigocheatsheet.com/)

[Second](https://gist.github.com/TSiege/cbb0507082bb18ff7e4b)

What confuses me is the terms **Indexing** and **Access** they use. Are they referring to the same thing?

Take **Array** as an example:

The first says Big O of Access is O(1). The second says Big O of Indexing is O(1). So I assume they are both saying given an index `x`, you can get the value of `array[x]` in O(1).

Take **Hash Table** as an example:

The first says Big O of Access is N/A. I think it's because with a Hash Table, you only do **searching** by a key. You don't retrieve a value by an index. But the second says Big O of Indexing is O(1). Maybe it's referring to **searching** this time?

Now take **Binary Tree** as an example:

The first: Access is O(logN). The second: Indexing is O(logN).

What?

So now they are both referring to **searching**? You can't retrieve a value from a Binary Tree by an index, right?

Please help me to gain some clarification. Thanks!

Comment: I think accessing and indexing don't really have fixed definitions in your articles.  Searching, however, can be more clearly defined: to find the element, if it exists, that matches a certain condition.  It's probably not so important to bother about exact terminology than to understand what each data structure can do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the above articles indexing and Access are meant to be the same thing, they both describe the asymptotic complexity required to have access at an element.

More specifically:

- In arrays, indexing or Access is of course O(1) when talking about
  accessing  for example 3rd element, and searching is O(n) due to
  linear pass required in worst case.
- In Hashtables it is well pointed that we can't refer to indexing e.g
  what is the 3rd element- this question has no point. First article
  says N/A taking into consideration the above notice. The second
  article considers Hashtable - indexing to be finding an element
  (where you know the hash key of the element). Then it is true that
  finding an element if you have a good hashtable (good length and of
  most important good hash function) it is almost consant time O(1).
- In binary trees finding - searching an element is O(logn). Here the
  first article by using the word accessing, is referred to searching
  an element as you have well pointed that out.  You can't retrieve a
  value from a Binary Tree by an index, but second article by indexing
  it means searching since indexing in other case wouldn't mean
  anything. Note that searching ( or accessing or indexing or
  searching) in binary search trees is not O(logn) but O(n) because
  imagine the case in which we insert sorted elements in tree (e.g
  1,2,3,4,5,...) then the tree becomes a list and searching is linear.
  Many times it is referred that it is O(logn) because the case where
  the elements are sorted is vary rare and most times it takes
  O(logn)(but this is asymptotic complexity of average case and not
  worst! ). You would get O(logn) if you use AVL trees where
  the tree is always balanced and searching is O(logn).

So in Hashtables and binary search trees in the above articles accessing-indexing is referred as searching.

Comment: So you are basically agreeing what I think, right? And you mentioned `Heap`. I think searching in Heap (Min Heap/Max Heap) is O(n), not O(logN).

Comment: BTW, for the binary tree, the way you explain it confuses me at first. First line `searching an element is O(logN)`. Then `Note that searching in binary search trees is not O(logN) but O(n)`. But I realized you were talking about average cases and worst cases.

Comment: Yes I agree with the first, Heap is a binary tree always balanced so searching is at most the height of the tree which is O(logn). As for BST imagine inserting 4,3,2,1 then the Binary Search Tree would be 4->3->2->1 which is typically a list and search becomes linear, big O is referred to worst case so we say it is O(n), but it is notable that in medium cases a BST will give O(logn) (but as I explained this is not the worst!).

Comment: [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap) is the heap definition I'm talking about. Searching should be O(n).

Comment: Yes you have right for heap it is O(n) (I was thinking about inserting in heap), I will edit the post, though AVL trees are O(logn) .